# Sprinkles are turning out different in rendering than they are in the view-port?

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, particles

[image: Screenshot of what the donut looks like in the viewport]

[image: rendered image of what the donut looks like.]

I'm just learning Blender, so bear with me if this solution is simple. The first image (the screenshot, through the camera) is what I want, but when I click to render the actual sprinkles on the donut become super small.

Comment: Any chance you use Compositor, and is there a node(s) affecting the sprinkles particle system? That's what's likely to affect your render.

Comment: All I'm using is the denoise node in the compositing tab.

Comment: Try to plug the viewer node into a node before the denoise node, then tell me how is it

Comment: I think I figured it out, the scale function in the particle properties had a keyframe, I think it was animating itself from a smaller to a larger size but I couldn't tell because I would only render one image. I just turned the keyframes off and now the sprinkles seem to be fine.